# Syntax to access Intersystems cache 2017.xx class properties with Python

Tags: python, caching, properties, intersystems

I have a Python (3.7) process to access a cache 2017.xx instance. I want to look at the properties of the existing databases for the instance. I can not seem to find the proper syntax. This is code snippet:

```
import codecs
import os
import sys
import intersys.pythonbind3 as pyb

url = "localhost[1972]:%SYS"
user= "xxxx"
password="zzzz"

conn    = pyb.connection()
conn.connect_now(url,user,password,None)

db      = pyb.database(conn)
qry     = pyb.query(db)
obj     = pyb.object(db)

# I get general database information with:
qry.prepare_class("SYS.Database",'CompactLocalList')
```

As I loop through the list of databases I want to get the property "MaxSize". The docs I have read mention creating connection to the current database (openId ?) and then accessing properties something like .get()

That is a rational approach but I can not figure out the proper syntax to to get a file handle If that is the proper term) to the current database

Answer (score 0):

After days of research I figured out the logic to get a handle to each of the cache databases. The method to use is the

```
_db = db.openid([class], directory,-1,-1)
```

In my case I am using the class = 'SYS.Database'

The directory is the dir for the current database (i.e. 'c:\intersystems\mgr\db')

From this I use the object getters/setters to get the property value:
maxSize = _db.get("MaxSize")

The getter can be used to get the value of any of the properties detailed in the 'SYS.Database' documentation. ( or any other cache class).